# Trouble with Ordered Trait in Scala

Tags: scala, natural-sort

I am attempting to define a natural ordering for distinct though similar classes of object. In Java I would use `Comparable`, and it seems the way to do the equivalent in Scala is with `Ordered`. I have the following trait:

```
trait Positioned extends Ordered[Positioned] {
  def position: Int = 1

  override def compare(that: Positioned): Int = position - that.position
}
```

I want to apply this trait to multiple case classes like this one:

```
case class Image(id: String,
                 override val position: Int = 1) extends Positioned
```

This complies just fine but at runtime when I call `sorted` on a collection of these `Image` objects, I get this error:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[com.myapp.Image]
starting with method $conforms in object Predef
```

Please let me know what this means and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Maybe this is related to [SI-8541](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8541)?

Comment: I saw that too, and it may very well be. But since the cases have some differences that might be significant, I still thought I'd ask. With all the compile magic Scala does, it is hard for me to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: By the way, slightly off-topic, but subtracting in a comparison method is incorrect if there is any chance of overflow. It would be safer, and slightly slower, to return `position.compare(that.position)`.

Comment: In this case that isn't likely, but thanks for the heads-up for next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely do what you're trying to do:

```
trait Positioned[T <: Positioned[T]] extends Ordered[T] {
  def position: Int = 1

  override def compare(that: T): Int = position - that.position
}

case class Image(id: String, override val position: Int = 1) extends Positioned[Image]
```

Inside of a scala REPL:

```
scala>  val imgs = Seq(Image("5", 5), Image("4", 4), Image("1", 1), Image("3", 3)) 
imgs: Seq[Image] = List(Image(5,5), Image(4,4),Image(1,1), Image(3,3))

scala>  imgs.sorted 
res1: Seq[Image] = List(Image(1,1), Image(3,3), Image(4,4), Image(5,5))
```

Comment: Why does this work, when `trait Positioned extends Ordered[Positioned]` doesn't?

Comment: Also, this doesn't let you compare `Image` instances with instances of other subclasses of `Positioned`.

Comment: @DavidMoles it can work, but you must call `imgs.sorted[Positioned]` -- this would allow you to sort anything that subclasses `Positioned`. I guess that it's unclear to me whether or not one would want subclasses of Positioned to be sortable.